# javax validation OneOf constraint

Tags: bean-validation, javax

Is there an annotation in javax validation, so it should constraint that value is one of predefined values.
Example

```
@OneOf(values = "12-14m, 16m, 18m")
private String size;
```

Comment: As it is a string field you can try to use `@Pattern` and combine the allowed things through or. Something like `@Pattern( regexp = "(12|13|14|16|18)m")`. But as suggested there's nothing like that by default. So either write your own, or try the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such constraint and you have to write it's own.

Here is the example that does mostly the same but opposite `@DenyValues`:

- annotation usage on a class: https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/66a2254e6d78c03d0b50531752d860efe784a1fd/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/controller/dto/AddCountryForm.java#L87
- annotation definition: https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/66a2254e6d78c03d0b50531752d860efe784a1fd/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/support/beanvalidation/DenyValues.java#L35-L44
- validator implementation: https://github.com/php-coder/mystamps/blob/66a2254e6d78c03d0b50531752d860efe784a1fd/src/main/java/ru/mystamps/web/support/beanvalidation/DenyValuesValidator.java#L26-L51

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [hibernate-validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/), you can declare new annotation using [`@ConstraintComposition`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ConstraintComposition.html). This is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560377/hibernate-validator-boolean-logic).